# Need to run Multiple JBoss applications on different web connectors

Tags: jboss, virtualhost, jboss6.x, virtual-hosts

I'm running a JBoss EAP 6 instance that has 5 applications running inside. Each one needs it's own socket bindings, web connector and thread pool.

I've defined 5 web connectors that bind to each socket binding group (one for each app) as well as their corresponding thread pools. But I'm not sure how to get a distinct url / address for each app.

Here's what I'd like:

http://myapp1.servername ->  app1

http://myapp2.servername -> app2

And so on..

I've scraped the web and found bits and pieces of how to do this, including virtual hosts. But I can't find anything coherent that helps me tie and app to it's corresponding connector and expose it via a separate url.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

To configure virtual host add below tag in 'web' subsystem:

```
 <virtual-server name="virtualserver1" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="app1">
        <alias name="app1.com"/>  
    </virtual-server>
```

Add below tag in war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/application</context-root> 
    <virtual-host>virtualserver1</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```